# How do I combine multiple statements in an Azure policy definition?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I want to create a custom Azure Policy JSON that reads through Azure resources and makes sure that it is following our standardized naming convention. For example, I am trying to set it up for virtual machines, cloud services, and Redis cache.

```
{
"if": {
    "allof": [
        {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
        },
        {
            "not": {
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "match": "gz?????????#?##"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
"then": {
    "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
}

"if": {
    "allof": [
        {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames"
        },
        {
            "not": {
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "match": "GZ?-??????-??#-???-??????-###"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
"then": {
    "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
}

"if": {
    "allof": [
        {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Cache/Redis"
        },
        {
            "not": {
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "match": "gz?????????#???###"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
"then": {
    "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
}
```

}

I don't think Azure allows for there to be multiple IFs like how I am trying to set it up. What I want it to do is this:

If the resource is a VM and it does not match that convention, then audit.
If the resource is a cloud service and it does not match that convention, then audit.
If the resource is Redis cache and it does not match that convention, then audit.

[Updated JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q88uK.png)

Answer (score 3):

You should use an [initiative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#initiatives) (policy set definition) to organize multiple related policies like this. This will be easier to maintain than a single policy definition with conditions for each resource type, and will allow you to see compliance results both for the entire naming convention policy set, and for each individual policy.

For example:

```
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Naming conventions",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "parameters": {
      "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "defaultValue": "Audit"
      }
    },
    "policyDefinitions": [
      {
        "policyDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/<YOUR VIRTUAL MACHINE NAMING CONVENTION POLICY ID>",
        "parameters": {
          "effect": {
            "value": "[parameters('effect')]"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "policyDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/<YOUR DOMAIN NAME NAMING CONVENTION POLICY ID>",
        "parameters": {
          "effect": {
            "value": "[parameters('effect')]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend it, but if you must combine multiple types in a single definition, then you may use `anyOf`, for example:

```
{
  "if": {
    "anyOf": [
      {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
          },
          {
            "not": {
                "field": "name",
                "match": "gz?????????#?##"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames"
          },
          {
            "not": {
              "field": "name",
              "match": "GZ?-??????-??#-???-??????-###"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "then" : {
    "effect" : "audit"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sapphiremirage,

May I ask why you don't recommend this? What problem could this lead to?

Comment: I don't recommend combining multiple types in a single definition because it can be difficult to maintain. When you add new types, or change the naming convention for a type, you have to (1) be careful not to break the policy definition while you're updating it (2) sift through all the other types in the compliance results while testing it. 

If each type has a separate policyDefinition, you can author/test/deploy independently. You can still get an overall compliance percentage for the scenario by putting them all in a policySetDefinition (initiative).

Comment: Hey Sapphiremirage,

At the moment, the only way I can do things for APM right now is to have multiple types in a definition. Would this be correct?